# Make separate text boxes for separate WordPress Custom Fields

Tags: custom-field, customization, wp-admin, metabox

I am trying to make usability of WordPress custom fields admin easier in my theme. I saw it in ElegantThemes' eStore theme. Only I couldn't figure out how to do it in my custom theme because I couldn't find the code in eStore theme files.

I use custom fields for my featured images and it's small thumbnail version. I have to upload both those pictures and from up above on the page, right below the title, copy the link and then choose the right custom key in custom fields below and paste it and the add it. Then repeat the process for another image.

[image]

I wanna make it simple. Make two text boxes and place the upload image button in front of them. As in the image below.

[image]

If possible I even wanna automate the copy and paste process. i.e.: The image link for the full size image automatically shows up in the text box on upload. Even elegant themes doesn't do that, but I would love to.

Any ideas on how I can do this. This will make the posting just a bit faster and more importantly make explaining the process to writers much much easier.

I am still looking into the code if I can find it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create metaboxes for the custom Post meta data for which you want to add UI. [Refer to `add_meta_box()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) for implementation documentation.

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, it would appear that, in order to change an *existing* Post custom metabox, you need to find the *callback function* referenced by `add_meta_box()`. Can you post some relevant code - primarily, the `add_meta_box()` calls themselves?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but that much I knew. I have add-meta-box as one of my tags. But I wanna add_meta_box for custom fields, which already exists on the page, only I wanna change the UI as above images show.

Comment: Hmm, okay - we'll get there! See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Once again A simple way to do that would be to use [**Verve Meta Boxes**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/verve-meta-boxes/) plugin which lets you define a metabox with a simple UI (no code is needed) and you have an options to add upload fields.